# Trying to set MYSQL password as root for the first time but I get an error message

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set the password for MYSQL for the first time as root and this is what I get .. Any reason as to why this is happening ?  Your assistance would be greatly appreciated

```
[root@sandy /]# mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you run `mysql_secure_installation` yet? This is necessary to prepare the MySQL environment (e.g., remove anonymous user access, test database and **set the root password**).